# How to get a dropdown with different background colors. Dropdown options are dynamic

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, sql

I want to get a dynamic dropdown with different backgroundcolors depending on the value. value: red -> backgroundcolor: red and so on...

Dropdown is filled by table in SQL-database.

Ampel

Comment: add your Code here you have tried out

Comment: <label title="Ampel">
        <span>Ampel</span>
        <select class="ampel", data-bind="options: $parent.allAmpel, value: ampelID, optionsText: 'dAm' , optionsValue: 'idA' ,optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" ></select>
      </label>

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do what you need.

```js
$('#mySelect > option').each(function() {

  $(this).css('background-color', $(this).val());

});

$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {

  $('#mySelect').css('background-color', $(this).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">

  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Does it also work for dynamic options? Because it‘s connected to a sql database with a table. ID: 1 description: red, ID: 2 description: yellow and so on...

Comment: <label title="Ampel">
                            <span>Ampel</span>
                            <select class="ampel", data-bind="options: $parent.allAmpel, value: ampelID, optionsText: 'dAm' , optionsValue: 'idA' ,optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" ></select>
                           
                        </label>

Comment: This is my code in html for the dropdown, which is connected to sql database

Comment: @ThyLe yes. Simply use the values from the database to update the "value" attribute on each option.

Comment: Thank you! Now I want the dropdown box to be the color that I've chosen in the dropdown list. Is that possible?